# sum of records in the same table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with columns: `ID, Name, Quantity, Price, Type, ...`

If I have 2 records with the same `Id` and `Name`, I want to find a way to add a record to the same table that has their sum of `Quantity`, sum of `Price` and `Type` equal to 2 .

Comment: if you add some sampe table data, and wanted output, it will be easier to help you!

Comment: here is an image : the records in yellow has column Quantity AND i want to add record to same table ! has the sum of that 

http://s22.postimg.org/l1gw8svtt/image.png

Comment: do you like copy/pasting from the image? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by clause to achieve this.

select sum(quantity),sum(price) from table1 group by id having id=2;

Comment: thanks for replay , the thing is this result how to add it to the original table as a record !

Comment: Trying following query. This might resolve your problem : INSERT INTO table1 (id, quantity,prices )
   SELECT d.id,  sum(quantity),sum(price) from table1 group by id having id=2;

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. But it is something like.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT MatId, 2, MatName, MatLaName, ParentID, LASTPURCHASEPRICED
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY MatId, MatName, MatLaName, ParentID, LASTPURCHASEPRICED
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```